# Having trouble installing .NET 5 on ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, package-management, dotnet

I had previously installed .NET products on multiple ubuntu servers just fine but just one particular server can't connect to microsoft servers apparently.

```
user@sv:~$ wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
--2021-02-03 10:01:35--  https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
Resolving packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)... 40.114.136.21
Connecting to packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)|40.114.136.21|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I want to know if there is an alternative way for me to install .NET 5 on this server

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `wget` or use `curl`:

```
curl -LO 'https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb'
```

Comment: It’s not about wget or curl even if I copy this file manually to server it will have issues connecting to microsoft after apt-install

Comment: @Shahriyar Then you should have mentioned that in your question!  I suggest you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1313236/edit) it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that your server’s internal clock is accurate? If the time is off by more than 15 minutes, SSL (and other) handshakes will fail.

If you need to have the time on an Ubuntu machine run with a different system time, such as when performing Y2038 testing or something similar, you can add `--no-check-certificate` to the `wget` command:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

However, there will still be the problem of installing software if the system clock is drastically out of alignment.

Comment: Just checked and unfortunately it wasn't the issue